# List array elements, one by one, with a click of a button

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to Javascript and working with the basics. I am wanting to create an array whose individual elements are randomly drawn, one at a time, with a click of a button, until all array elements are displayed on the screen. The code I have is almost there. But the issue is that when it runs, it always grabs 2 elements on the first button click, rather than 1. It runs well for the remaining elements. Sure would appreciate some insight to this problem. Thank you.

```
var myArray=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
var text = "";
var i;

function RandomDraw() {
    for(i = 0; i < myArray.length; i+=text) {
        var ri = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
        var rs = myArray.splice(ri, 1);
        document.getElementById("showSplice").innerHTML = text+=rs;
        //document.getElementById("showArrayList").innerHTML = myArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use a for loop, when you only want 1 per click? Just remove the for loop and add a `if(myArray.length > 0)`

Comment: `i+=text` makes no sense.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, Niels. That may not be the final answer I am looking for. With a click of the button, the code is randomly grabbing and displaying each element. But with the click of the button, the previous element displayed is being removed from the screen and the next element presented. I am trying to have each element remain on the screen as the button is clicked (until the entire array is displayed). A little more help, please.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Ibrahim. Looking at the responses, I see I was not clear enough in what I was looking to do (I have edited my question). The important thing for me to do is to display each element on the screen, as the button is clicked, in a continuous fashion. One element presents (and remains) on the screen, followed by the next. So that when all elements of the array have been removed, all elements are presented on the screen, together. Your help is greatly appreciated. -Don

Answer (score 1):

It *"always"* draws 2 elements because of the `i+=text`. Your array is small thus the loop needs 2 iteration (of cocatinating the strings to get the number `i`) to go over `myArray.length`.

```
First iteration:
   i = 0 => 0 < myArray.length => true
   prints number
Second iteration: (say '4' get choosen)
   i = i + text and text = '4' => i = "04" => "04" < myArray.length => true
   prints number
Third iteration: (say '3' get choosen)
   i = i + text and text = '43' => i = "0443" => "0443" < myArray.length => false
   loop breaks
```

So there is a possibility that two elements get printed. Depending on the length of the array, there could be more.

You don't need the loop, just choose a number and print it:

```
function RandomDraw() {
    if(myArray.length > 0) {                                     // if there still elements in the array
        var ri = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);     // do your job ...
        var rs = myArray.splice(ri, 1);
        document.getElementById("showSplice").textContent = rs;  // .textContent is better
    }
    else {
        // print a message indicating that the array is now empty
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to shuffle the array and then, on each click, `pop` the element from the shuffled array.

```js
function shuffle(array) {
  return array.sort(function() { return Math.random() - 0.5; });
}

var button       = document.getElementById('button');
var origin       = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7'];
var myArray      = shuffle(origin);
var currentValue = null;

button.onclick = function() {
  currentValue = myArray.pop();

  if(!!currentValue) {
    console.log(currentValue);
  }
}
```

```html
<button id='button'>
get element
</button>
```

You can shuffle the array again on each click, but I think it is not necessary whatsoever...

If you're wondering about `Math.random() - 0.5`:

> [...] `Math.random` is returning a number between 0 and 1. Therefore, if you call `Math.random() - 0.5` there is a 50% chance you will get a negative number and 50% chance you'll get a positive number.
>   If you run a for loop and add these results in an array, you will effectively get a full distribution of negative and positive numbers.

- https://teamtreehouse.com/community/mathrandom05

Comment: I would prefer doing it this way because it's easy to reset.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
let myArray=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
function RandomDraw(){
  const selectedIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
  const selected = myArray[selectedIndex]
  myArray = myArray.slice(0, selected).concat(myArray.slice(selected + 1));
  return selected;
}
```

Every time you call `RandomDraw` it will return a random number, without repeating.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it, you want to draw every items from the array after a single click. So the loop is needed.

As others have said, there are several issues in your for loop :

- that i+= text makes no sense
- you are looping until i reaches the length of your array, but you are splicing that array, hence reducing its length

You could correct your for loop :

```
function RandomDraw() {
    var length = myArray.length;
    var ri = 0;
    for (var i=0;i<length;i++) {
        ri = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
        console.log("Random index to be drawn : " + ri);

        // removing that index from the array : 
        myArray.splice(ri, 1);

        console.log("myArray after a random draw : ", myArray);
    }
}
```

Or, you could use a while loop :

```
function RandomDraw() {
    var ri = 0;
    while (myArray.length > 0) {
        ri = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
        console.log("Random index to be drawn : " + ri);

        // removing that index from the array : 
        myArray.splice(ri, 1);

        console.log("myArray after a random draw : ", myArray);
    }
}
```